# Where does the mongoose code is executed?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a question, where does the mongoose code is executed, is it on the node.js thread or mongodb api, is it offloading like the queries and all that stuff to mongodb instance, and also when i define mongoose virtual when it's running, where does it run?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the mongoose code is executed in the node thread, but queries are served by a process running on the network, on a different computer (potentially) and as such it must have its own processes and threads, which are used to query and return the data.  I am not familiar with the product "mongoose virtual".

Comment: What do u mean by mongoose code? do u mean the configuration and schema declaration and all stuff that doesn't require database interaction?! Here u can check out virtuals: mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Comment: Your post states "where does the mongoose code is executed".  I am referring to that.  What do you mean when you say "where does the mongoose code is executed"?